# Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge 11.6 (32-bit) Crash when enter .NET events

Tags: .net, eclipse, crash, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm using .NET GUI for the project, sometimes the program **(Progress Developer Studio 11.6 32-bit)** went not responding when I make an event by GUI properties especially on new event.

Other info :

OS : Windows 10 (64-bit)

java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)

---

**eclipse.ini**

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835

-showsplash
com.progress.tools.branding

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-name

Progress Developer Studio

-vm

C:/OpenEdge11.6/jre/bin/javaw.exe

-vmargs

-Xms768m

-Xmx768m

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

---

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulo9c.png)

How to prevent the crashes? Does it affected by eclipse.ini Xms Xmx value?

Thank you.

Comment: Empty your .metadata\.log file and check for Exceptions there. They may help to indicate what's going on.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when using the Java version that ships with OpenEdge? The java version shipped with my 11.6.3 installation is 1.7.0_45-b18. Just suggesting this - as I previously experienced issues with the Visual Designer when using not the default Eclipse and Java version.

Comment: It still crash when using the Java version that ships with OpenEdge, the main issue here is the OS. After running Developer Studio with compatibility mode Windows 7, crash doesn't happen until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the Eclipse and Java version that ships with OpenEdge. You can try the following alternative startup parameters:

C:\Progress\OpenEdge116\oeide\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:/Progress/OpenEdge116/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll"

where c:\Progress\OpenEdge116 is the installation folder of OpenEdge 11.6.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative startup parameters can be found in Progress Developer Studio shortcut (.lnk) properties. Just copy-paste your current shortcut and replace the startup with the new one.

In my case :

Previous startup (target) :

C:\OpenEdge11.6\oeide\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean  -vm "C:\OpenEdge11.6\jre\bin\javaw.exe"

---

New startup (target) :

C:\OpenEdge11.6\oeide\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean  -vm "C:\OpenEdge11.6\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Comment: [Update] : 
Crash still happened in Windows 10 Pro 64-bit on large class file size, Run Compatibility Mode Windows 7 solved the crash. Hope this helps!

Comment: [Update] : Crash still happened sometimes. (Eclipse not responding) in task manager.

Comment: Kill task and delete .snap file to make it works again